# Python Using Keyword and variable number of arguments in same function

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, arguments

I am wondering if there is a way to do something like this in python 2.7.12

```
def saveValues(file,*data,delim="|"):
    buf=""
    for d in data:
       buf+=str(d) + delim
    open(file,"w").write(buf[:-1])
```

So that I have the option to pass delim, or take the default.

Comment: Have you tried this out as-is? I think it should work.

Comment: @MattCremeens  that's a syntax error

Comment: Nope... doesn't work in 2.7... may work in 3, but I'm on an imbedded device where I got to use what I have.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible in Python 3.0+, after implementation of [PEP 3102 -- Keyword-Only Arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/).  The syntax would be exactly how you've shown it, in fact.

The usual workaround for Python 2 is this:

```
def saveValues(file, *data, **kwargs):
    delim = kwargs.pop('delim', '|')
    ...
```